# Smart Table (AngularJs) async data change not updating

Tags: angularjs, ajax, smart-table

I have a table, made using Smart Table in AngularJs.

I am trying to fetching new data and adding to this table using ajax. I push to `$scope.rowCollection` in ajax call back. However why the newly added data is not displaying in the table? (I am using `st-safe-src`, and I am adding new data to the collection in `st-safe-src`.)

Another question is: do I have to add `$scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);` every time `st-safe-src` is changed? (adding this line does not solve the issue)

I created this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sH7J8NCBqgv5A8Q7timw?p=preview) with timeout to simulate the ajax call back.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add some of your code and make a plunker. This way more peeps are inclined to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your plunkr by updating the timeout code so that invoked `$scope.$apply`.  You should use `$scope.$apply` to make sure that angular JS components are notified that angular JS models have been changed when you use a non-angular AJAX call (like jQuery) or with core JS callbacks (like jQuery):  http://plnkr.co/edit/iI7zpSjmB2db4ryHuzp7?p=preview

```
      // use $timeout service so that we can automatically invoke 
      // the appropriate apply
      $timeout(function () {
        $scope.rowCollection.push({firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'});
        // do I need this?
        $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
        console.log("executed");
      }, 2000, true);
```

You could also do this as follows:

```
      setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          $scope.rowCollection.push({firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'});
          // do I need this?
          $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
        });
        console.log("executed");
      }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks! And I have tested, I don't need `$scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);`. Wonder why a lot of people on the internet added that line.